# I want to do "or where" and "concat" with the query builder of cakephp4

Tags: php, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

At first , I apologize for my poor English.

environmental information
language: PHP 7.4.13
framework: CakePHP 4.2.6

At the SQL DB table, there are 6 colmuns.
(columnA , columnB , columnC , columnD , columnE , columnF)

I want to search from the concatnated columns.
I want to "OR search" with 4 conditions.

Whether '${columnA}.${columnC}' matches $str
or
Whether '${columnB}.${columnC}' matches $str
or
Whether '${columnD}.${columnF}' matches $str
or
Whether '${columnE}.${columnF}' matches $str

Now , I write as this to search with one condition .

```
$query->where(function ($exp, $q) use($str) {
    $concat = $q->func()->concat([
        'columnA' => 'identifier', 
        'columnC' => 'identifier'
    ]);
    return $exp->like($concat, '%' . $str . '%' );
});
```

If I search from "not concatnated columns" , I write this .

```
$query->where([
    0 => [
        'or' => [
            '${columnA} LIKE' => '%' . $str . '%' ,
            '${columnB} LIKE' => '%' . $str . '%' ,
            '${columnC} LIKE' => '%' . $str . '%' ,
            '${columnD} LIKE' => '%' . $str . '%' ,
        ]
    ],

]);
```

Finally , I want to do something like this.(Ofcourse , this throws a syntax error )

```
$query->where([
    0 => [
        'or' => [
            '${columnA}.${columnC} LIKE' => '%' . $str . '%' ,
            '${columnB}.${columnC} LIKE' => '%' . $str . '%' ,
            '${columnD}.${columnF} LIKE' => '%' . $str . '%' ,
            '${columnE}.${columnF} LIKE' => '%' . $str . '%' ,
        ]
    ],

]);
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query expression object has an `or()` method that you can use, it either takes an array of conditions that are combined using `OR`, or a callable that receives a new query expression object that uses the `OR` operator.

In any case you need to be aware that `QueryExpression::like()` will *not* return a new expression object, but it will add a new like expression to the current query expression object's stack instead.

That being said, the callback variant would look something like this:

```php
$query->where(function (
    \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
    \Cake\ORM\Query $q
) use (
    $str
) {
    return $exp->or(function ($exp) use ($q, $str) {
        $concatAC = $q->func()->concat([
            'columnA' => 'identifier',
            'columnC' => 'identifier'
        ]);
        $concatBC = $q->func()->concat([
            'columnB' => 'identifier', 
            'columnC' => 'identifier'
        ]);
        
        return $exp
            ->like($concatAC, '%' . $str . '%')
            ->like($concatBC, '%' . $str . '%')
            // ...
    });
});
```

The former variant can be used by passing an empty array, that way you receive an empty query expression object that you can then fill with your conditions:

```php
$query->where(function (
    \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
    \Cake\ORM\Query $q
) use (
    $str
) {
    // ...

    return $exp
        ->or([])
        ->like($concatAC, '%' . $str . '%')
        ->like($concatBC, '%' . $str . '%')
        // ...
});
```

Lastly you can also at any point change the string used for concatenating the expressions by any query expression object using `QueryExpression::setConjunction()`:

```php
$query->where(function (
    \Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression $exp,
    \Cake\ORM\Query $q
) use (
    $str
) {
    // ...

    return $exp
        ->setConjunction('OR')
        ->like($concatAC, '%' . $str . '%')
        ->like($concatBC, '%' . $str . '%')
        // ...
});
```

All three variants will result in the same SQL, that is:

```sql
WHERE (
    CONCAT(columnA, columnC) LIKE %...% OR
    CONCAT(columnB, columnC) LIKE %...% OR
    ...
)
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Advanced Conditions](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)**

Comment: Thank you for your advice.
I tried it and it successfully worked.